# Parse in swift is very slow - my programming at fault ?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a main class in Parse, which feeds a table view in swift. the background image covers the whole of the background. These images are 480k in size. They do not always turn up on the tableviewcell (I know I can add an placeholder image). I have a very faster connection to my mobile.. If i use 4g they don't even turn up at all.

Here is my function for pulling the images down. I don't really know what else I can do.

```
func loadImages() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "TableViewData")
    query.orderByDescending("objectId")


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if(error == nil){

            let imageObjects = objects as [PFObject]

            for object in objects {

                let thumbNail = object["backgroundImage"] as PFFile

                thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                        self.CellBackgroundImage.append(image!)
                        println(self.CellBackgroundImage.count)
                    }

                })

            }

        }
        else{
            println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
        }

    })


}
```

As you can see I add them as a an array and the tableview will show them according to the index.path.

Can anyone suggest anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to the user interface must always be performed on the main thread.  Asynchronous networking completions are typically called on a background thread (not sure about PFQuery stuff), so you need to force the update to happen on the correct thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.CellBackgroundImage.append(image!)
}
```